# Mapbox iOS GL black background layer issue

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I try to implement raster tiles in `mapbox-iOS-SDK gl 3.2.3`

This is my local style source:

```
{
"version": 8,
"name": "2GIS tiles",
"sources": {
    "mainSource": {
        "type": "raster",
        "tiles": [
                  "http://tile1.maps.2gis.com/tiles?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&v=1"
                  ],
        "tileSize": 128
    }
},
"layers": [
           {
           "id": "background",
           "type": "background",
           "paint": {
               "fill-color": "#FFF9E8"
           }
           },
           {
           "id": "mainLayer",
           "type": "raster",
           "source": "mainSource",
           "paint": {
               "raster-fade-duration": 100
           }
           }
           ]
}
```

And here what I get [click-me](https://gyazo.com/d222897ee99793d12e4ccb7960598cc2)

So, while scrolling or panning the map - black background appeared sometimes while tiles are loading.

How can I solve this? Is it possible to change the black color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `paint` property from `fill-color` to `background-color`.

E.g.,

```
{
  "id": "background",
  "type": "background",
  "paint": {
    "background-color": "#FFF9E8"
  }
}
```

The [Mapbox GL Style Reference](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#paint-background-color) mentions this for `paint`, which should explain the black background you are seeing.

> `background-color`
>   Optional color.  **Defaults to #000000**. Disabled by background-pattern.
>   The color with which the background will be drawn.